# Line connecting nodes not starting from prescribed anchor position in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

This MWE code is adapted from [this](http://This%20MWE%20code%20is%20adapted%20from%20this%20example%20on%20www.texample.net%20and%20was%20originally%20written%20by%20SE%20user%20cfr:) example on www.texample.net and was originally written by SE user [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, calc, shadows}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\colorlet{mygreen}{green!75!black}
\colorlet{col1in}{red!30}
\colorlet{col1out}{red!40}
\colorlet{col2in}{mygreen!40}
\colorlet{col2out}{mygreen!50}
\colorlet{col3in}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col3out}{blue!40}
\colorlet{col4in}{mygreen!20}
\colorlet{col4out}{mygreen!30}
\colorlet{col5in}{blue!10}
\colorlet{col5out}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6in}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6out}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col7out}{orange}
\colorlet{col7in}{orange!50}
\colorlet{col8out}{orange!40}
\colorlet{col8in}{orange!20}
\colorlet{linecol}{blue!60}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  basic/.style  = {draw, drop shadow, rectangle},
  root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
                   fill=green!30},
  level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=blue!10},
  level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=green!10}
}

\pgfkeys{/forest,
  rect/.append style   = {rectangle, rounded corners = 2pt,
                         inner color = col6in, outer color = col6out},
  ellip/.append style  = {ellipse, inner color = col5in,
                          outer color = col5out},
  orect/.append style  = {rect, font = \sffamily\bfseries\LARGE,
                         text width = 325pt, text centered,
                         minimum height = 10pt, outer color = col7out,
                         inner color=col7in},
  oellip/.append style = {ellip, inner color = col8in, outer color = col8out,
                          font = \sffamily\bfseries\large, text centered}}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1.2\textwidth,center}    
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={
          font=\sffamily\bfseries,
          line width=1pt,
          draw=linecol,
          ellip,
          align=center,
          child anchor=north,
          parent anchor=south,
          drop shadow,
          l sep+=12.5pt,
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
              >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->, \forestoption{edge}]
              (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -|
              (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
          where level={3}{tier=tier3}{},
          where level={0}{l sep-=15pt}{},
          where level={1}{
            if n={1}{
              edge path={
                \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
                  >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->,
                  \forestoption{edge}]
                  (!u.west) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
                },
            }{
              edge path={
                \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
                  >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->,
                  \forestoption{edge}]
                  (!u.east) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
                },
            }
          }{},
      }
      [\Huge Total drag, yshift = 3cm, inner color=col1in, outer color=col1out
        [\huge Viscous drag, yshift = 1cm, inner color=col2in, outer color=col2out
          [\Large Displacement separation, inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out
          ]
          [\Large Boundary layer shear, inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out 
          ]
        ]
        [\huge Vortex drag, yshift = 1cm, inner color=col3in, outer color=col3out
          [\Large Trailing vortices due to lift
          ]
        ]
        [\huge Wave drag, yshift = 1cm, inner color=col3in, outer color=col3out
              [\Large Waves due to lift
              ]
              [\Large Waves due to volume
              ]
        ]  
        ]
       ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

results in this:

[image]

Note that the lines coming from the upper level parent node labeled 'Total drag' do not start from the prescribed 'South' anchor location, as prescribed in the lines:

```
for tree={
      ...
      parent anchor=south,
      ...
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: The value of `parent anchor` (which is set to south) is actually not used to draw the offending edge, as that edge is drawn using the third occurrence of `edge path`.

Comment: Remarks. (i) next time, a *working* minimal example would be appreciated. (ii) Using `where level` inside `for tree` results in a double loop! You should use `if level`. (Well, in your case, the result is the same, but the `if` version is faster.)

Comment: Hi, sorry I thought the entire figure code would be enough for a MWE but I realise now that the point behind it is that people must be able to simply copy and paste the code and it should run on their system. i updated the question. Can you perhaps indicate what I should add to my code under the 3rd instance of edge path? I tried a few things but don't get it to work.

Comment: Replace `(!u.east)` by `(!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt)`, as in the first occurrence of `edge path`. And I really urge you to clean up the code! Maybe define a style for your fancy edges ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as expected. `edges` between first node and children is defined with

```
     where level={1}{
        if n={1}{
          edge path=...
        }{
          edge path=...
        }
      }{},
```

Therefore, for all children a *new* parent anchor is defined. This is `west` for child 1 and `east` for all other children except 1.

If you want to distinguish between child 2 and 3, you could introduce another `if` level.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, calc, shadows}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\colorlet{mygreen}{green!75!black}
\colorlet{col1in}{red!30}
\colorlet{col1out}{red!40}
\colorlet{col2in}{mygreen!40}
\colorlet{col2out}{mygreen!50}
\colorlet{col3in}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col3out}{blue!40}
\colorlet{col4in}{mygreen!20}
\colorlet{col4out}{mygreen!30}
\colorlet{col5in}{blue!10}
\colorlet{col5out}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6in}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6out}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col7out}{orange}
\colorlet{col7in}{orange!50}
\colorlet{col8out}{orange!40}
\colorlet{col8in}{orange!20}
\colorlet{linecol}{blue!60}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  basic/.style  = {draw, drop shadow, rectangle},
  root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
                   fill=green!30},
  level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=blue!10},
  level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=green!10}
}

\pgfkeys{/forest,
  rect/.append style   = {rectangle, rounded corners = 2pt,
                         inner color = col6in, outer color = col6out},
  ellip/.append style  = {ellipse, inner color = col5in,
                          outer color = col5out},
  orect/.append style  = {rect, font = \sffamily\bfseries\LARGE,
                         text width = 325pt, text centered,
                         minimum height = 10pt, outer color = col7out,
                         inner color=col7in},
  oellip/.append style = {ellip, inner color = col8in, outer color = col8out,
                          font = \sffamily\bfseries\large, text centered}}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1.2\textwidth,center}    
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={
          font=\sffamily\bfseries,
          line width=1pt,
          draw=linecol,
          ellip,
          align=center,
          child anchor=north,
          parent anchor=south,
          drop shadow,
          l sep+=12.5pt,
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
              >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->, \forestoption{edge}]
              (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -|
              (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
          if level={3}{tier=tier3}{},
          if level={0}{l sep-=15pt}{},
          if level={1}{
            if n={1}{
              edge path={
                \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
                  >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->,
                  \forestoption{edge}]
                  (!u.west) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
                },
            }{
              if n={3}{
                edge path={
                    \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
                    >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->,
                    \forestoption{edge}]
                    (!u.east) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
                    },
                }{}}
          }{},
      }
      [\Huge Total drag, yshift = 3cm, inner color=col1in, outer color=col1out
        [\huge Viscous drag, yshift = 1cm, inner color=col2in, outer color=col2out
          [\Large Displacement separation, inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out
          ]
          [\Large Boundary layer shear, inner color=col4in, outer color=col4out 
          ]
        ]
        [\huge Vortex drag, yshift = 1cm, inner color=col3in, outer color=col3out
          [\Large Trailing vortices due to lift
          ]
        ]
        [\huge Wave drag, yshift = 1cm, inner color=col3in, outer color=col3out
              [\Large Waves due to lift
              ]
              [\Large Waves due to volume
              ]
        ]  
        ]
       ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ignasi's answer is good. This is just a supplement. If you also want to get rid of the kink in the line, you can use the `else...` part of the final `if...` to align the child with the parent:

```
  if level=1{
    if n=1{
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.west) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
    }{
      if n'=1{
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.east) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
      }{calign with current}
    }
  }{},
```

[image: less kinky line]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shadows}
\usepackage{forest}

\colorlet{mygreen}{green!75!black}
\colorlet{col1in}{red!30}
\colorlet{col1out}{red!40}
\colorlet{col2in}{mygreen!40}
\colorlet{col2out}{mygreen!50}
\colorlet{col3in}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col3out}{blue!40}
\colorlet{col4in}{mygreen!20}
\colorlet{col4out}{mygreen!30}
\colorlet{col5in}{blue!10}
\colorlet{col5out}{blue!20}
\colorlet{linecol}{blue!60}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  ellip/.append style  = {ellipse, col in out = 5},
  col in out/.style = {inner color = col#1in, outer color = col#1out},
  font sizing/.style={font=\sffamily\bfseries#1},
  Huge/.style={font sizing=\Huge},
  huge/.style={font sizing=\huge},
  Large/.style={font sizing=\Large},
}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
      font=\sffamily\bfseries,
      line width=1pt,
      draw=linecol,
      ellip,
      align=center,
      child anchor=north,
      parent anchor=south,
      drop shadow,
      l sep+=10mm,
      edge={color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt, >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->},
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
      if level=1{
        huge,
        if n=1{
          col in out=2,
          for children={col in out=4},
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.west) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
        }{
          col in out=3,
          if n'=1{
            edge path={
              \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.east) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
          }{calign with current}
        }
      }{},
      if level=2{Large}{}
  }
  [Total drag, Huge, col in out=1
    [Viscous drag
      [Displacement separation
      ]
      [Boundary layer shear
      ]
    ]
    [Vortex drag
      [Trailing vortices due to lift
      ]
    ]
    [Wave drag
          [Waves due to lift
          ]
          [Waves due to volume
          ]
    ]
   ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```